# JavaScript: Extract one element out of an array that is created after php json encode

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var Array = [["1","123","3","3","3","20"],["2","253","2","2","2","15"],["3","222","4","4","4","15"],["4","353","5","5","5","15"]];
alert(Array[0][0]);
```

This prints only [. Please suggest how to print a single element in a loop out of the array. Or just a single element of the first array elements.

Comment: This code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/vymdwvhe/ fiddle

Comment: yes but if it is used inside $(function (){ it doesn't.

Comment: Then this code is not [mcve]. Please show real code which __not works__

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7o6zaguu/ It doesn't alert anything though when I use on my local server it prints [

Comment: JSON is actually a string with particular format. That it prints '[' with alert(Array[0][0]) suggests that the inner elements are being seen as strings. Also, I think that Array is actually the name of a constructor, so that may result in something unexpected

Comment: var x = new Array();
console.log(typeof x);

Comment: Thanks Zach, I identified the problem as the data came after a php json_encode and I put them inside a single quote in JavaScript like this var xyz = '<?php echo $data; ?>'; that was causing the problem. Thank you all for your help and being kind!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$Array = [["1","123","3","3","3","20"],["2","253","2","2","2","15"],    ["3","222","4","4","4","15"],["4","353","5","5","5","15"]];
foreach($arrays as $array){
   foreach($array as $val){
     echo $val.'<br>';
   }
```

}

> in Javascript

```
var Arrays = [["1","123","3","3","3","20"],["2","253","2","2","2","15"],["3","222","4","4","4","15"],["4","353","5","5","5","15"]];
 var val='';
 var i=0;var j=0; 
 for(i=0;i<Arrays.length;i++){
  var temp=Arrays[i];
      for(j=0 ;j<temp.length;j++){
             alert(Arrays[i][j]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Use php instead of js? Hmmmm

Comment: is there any foreach in javascript, never knew it!

Comment: there is a `Array.forEach()` in javascript but you do not use it in this way